# Display value with space from database

Tags: php, mysql, html

In my form, I have a TextArea Box in which user can input multiple lines in it.

Example of the input;

```
1) Adam
2) Joe
3) Zack
```

After I saved the input in the database and I display it in a table. The output will become like this ;

```
1) Adam 2) Joe 3) Zack
```

This is the code;

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $sis_sistem ?></td>

</tr>   
    </table>
```

The variable $sis_sistem holds the data that I called from the database.

The problem is that is not what I want for it to display. So how am I going to display it exactly like the user's input before?

Like this;

```
1) Adam
2) Joe
3) Zack
```

I don't know what happened but when I try back the nl2br() functions several times, it worked. Thank you all and sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: There are a lot of down votes on answers here so I like to [quote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down): `Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php echo nl2br($system); ?>
```

Your lines breaks might be saved as \n in the database, but you need to use the HTML 
 tag in a web page.

Answer (score 2):

wrong usage of textarea element. should be:

```
<textarea>$system</textarea>
```

Comment: in that case nl2br() would do it. or use <pre>$system</pre>

Comment: in that case problem is with your data. go in to mysql console and select value from db. do you see newlines there. if no, go back and check how you store the value.

Comment: It display as it should be when I display it back in the Textarea box. So the data in the database is not the problem. The problem only occur when I try to display it in a table.

Comment: okay, that just confirms that you have either "\n" or "\n\r" sequences in your string, which in html are not displayed. usually <pre> tag or nl2br() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) fixes that. if that does not help, problem is elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Place your content into the textarea. Don't `echo` to much html and use " around html attribute values:

```
?><td><TEXTAREA NAME="system" ROWS="4" COLS="40"><?= $system ?></TEXTAREA></td><?
```

Comment: Down vote with no comment and no good reason. This makes me unmotivated to help here.

Comment: Thank you. Motivation is up again :D

Answer (score -1):

Try the [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) built-in function

```
<?php echo nl2br($system) ?>
```

Comment: textarea doesn;t have a value attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: Down grade my answer if you want @Quamis but I just copy/pasted **his** code and added the `nl2br` function.

Answer (score -1):

Try;

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top"><?php echo nl2br($sis_sistem) ?></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: @HafizAbdullah **WHAT CERTAINLY** didn't work? Can't you be more informative?

Comment: The output still display horizontally.